# Exception updating game to cocos2d-x v2.0

Tags: android, java-native-interface, shared-libraries, cocos2d-x

I'm working on linux + eclipse.

I have updated my code following the steps provided by the wiki.

1º I create a new eclipse project.
2º I run hello world and it works.
3º I put my old code on Classes, and resources.
4º I update appdelegate.cpp .h, and jni/Android.mk with new files.
5º It compile correctly.

6º Lauching from eclipse i get the following exception:

```
trying to load lib /data/data/org.pipero.game/lib/libgame.so
Fatal signal 11.
```

Something is wrong, but i don't know what is happening.

The same code work on a xcode project.
I don't get the CCLOG message con Appdelegate constructor, and on Java_org_cocos2dx_lib_Cocos2dxRenderer_nativeInit on main.cpp neither.

LOGCAT:

```
---- LOG TEST RUNNING HELLO WORLD ------
06-13 18:29:07.189: D/dalvikvm(11613): Trying to load lib /data/data/pipero.corporation.nyan/lib/libgame.so 0x40f87190
06-13 18:29:07.199: D/dalvikvm(11613): Added shared lib /data/data/pipero.corporation.nyan/lib/libgame.so 0x40f87190
06-13 18:29:07.269: W/apk path(11613): /data/app/pipero.corporation.nyan-2.apk
06-13 18:29:07.409: D/SurfaceView(11613): pckname = pipero.corporation.nyan
06-13 18:29:07.809: D/libEGL(11613): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLES_android.so
06-13 18:29:07.859: D/libEGL(11613): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_mali.so
06-13 18:29:07.919: D/libEGL(11613): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_mali.so
06-13 18:29:07.929: D/libEGL(11613): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_mali.so
------------------------------------- OK -------------------------------

---- LOG TEST RUNNING TEST changing android files to mine ------
06-13 18:36:31.789: D/dalvikvm(12046): Trying to load lib /data/data/pipero.corporation.nyan/lib/libgame.so 0x40f8de18
06-13 18:36:31.799: A/libc(12046): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000030 (code=1)
--------------------------------------- FAIL --------------------------
```

I have try to compile in another tablet (An Android 3.2) And i getting the same problem. This time the log is:

06-12 15:16:16.610: I/DEBUG: * *
06-12 15:16:16.610: I/DEBUG: Build fingerprint: 'asus/WW_epad/TF101:3.2.1/HTK75/WW_epad-8.6.5.13-20110925:user/release-keys'
06-12 15:16:16.610: I/DEBUG: pid: 1183, tid: 1183 >>> pipero.corp.test

So, signal 11 SEGV_MAPERR, i assume that is a problem with the compilation, the library is found, but the program cannot load it correctly. The JNI not execute jni_Onload.

Some idea???

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you might find a cocos2d-x bug. Usually when your code could compile on both xcode and ndk, and received fatal signal only on one platform, means something wrong with the framework.  You did re-build your source code using ./build_native.sh in the new project folder right? I haven't merge my code to 2.0 since it is not stable enough and to many code changes such as CCTouchDispatcher is moved into CCDirector, etc. Couldn't help much.

Comment: Yes, i tried to rebuild 3 times. And create a new project 3 times too. That happen to me first time on XCode project, but the second time worked fine. I don´t know what was different

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you are getting fatal signal 11 maybe you want to have a look at [this](http://www.bitwizard.nl/sig11/). It is a segmentation fault, accessing a memory location that was not assigned, usually due to a programing bug.

Good luck, but as some people have no problems with the new version the most likely case is that you have a programing bug that with the old version was not giving problems.

Comment: The problem is, the library is not loaded, in 1 case, log cat say: 06-13 18:29:07.199: D/dalvikvm(11613): Added shared lib /data/data/pipero.corporation.nyan/lib/libgame.so 0x40f87190; but when i use my code no appear that line, so, lib is not loaded, so, segmentation 11 because functions are not found.

Comment: Look if you have the libraries, if you have them, try changing the path to a simpler one, just in case. I don't like to think that it is a cocos-2d bug, I always think it's my fault, but who knows...

Answer (score 3):

Inside your project folder, double check that the lib file is actually inside your android libs folder.

[cocos2d-x root]/[game_name]/android/libs

There should be one file called libgame.so inside there.

If it compiles ok, the .so file should be generated.  When you compile, I find it helpful to "Refresh" the project in eclipse so that eclipse rescans the directories for any new files/modifications to pack into the APK file for deploying.

There is an option you can enable in eclipse to automatically detect file system changes I believe, but I'm not sure where that options is.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The libgame.so exist into the libs/armeabi folder, i have tried to refresh, but its happening the same thing.

Comment: How about inside your launching activity in Java land (the one that extends Cocos2dxActivity)?  Do you have a 

static { System.loadLibrary("game"); } 

somewhere in there?  That's the only thing I can think of..

Comment: static {
         System.loadLibrary("game");
     } is used on the general java, inside the onCreate. The project generated automatically works (use too libgame.so) but changing the code for mine, don't work.